# Office365に、社内のSharePointサーバーからアクセスしたい

Tags: c#, oauth, sharepoint

方式的な質問ですが、どなたか教えてください。
社内のSharePointに置くプログラム（Feature）から、自社で契約しているOffice365にアクセスしたいのですが、認証方法は、OAuth2を利用しなければいけないのでしょうか?
また、c#でプログラムを作るときに、参考になるWebサイトがあれば教えてください。